# How to alter submission data when inserting a submission

Tags: hooks, webforms, 9

I am trying to alter the data in a webform submission before this is being saved in to the database.

In D7 i would do something like this:

```
function mymodule_webform_submission_presave($node, &$submission){
  if($submission->nid == 1234){ 
    $n = node_load(4321);
    $value = $n->field_value['und'][0]['value'];
    $submission->data[2][0] = $value;
  }
}
```

However I am not able to achieve the same in Drupal 9. I have tried using some of the `hook_webform_handler_invoke_alter` and `hook_webform_handler_invoke_METHOD_NAME_alter` hooks listed in webform.api.php without success. Are these the correct hooks to use, I have not been able to identify any "submission_presave" hooks in the Drupal 9 version of webform module (currently v 6.2.2).
Any help or guidance toward the best solution would be appreciated.

Comment: `webform_submission` is an entity type, so you'd use `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave` - which gives you the same function name as your Drupal 7 version. You'll need to change the function signature (first arg will be `$entity`, the submission), and the method body to manipulate the new entity structure, but that's where you'd do it

Comment: Clive, thank you for your answer, I appreciate it :) -- I have tried that hook as well, but I must be doing something wrong.
I have tried a function called mymodule_webform_submission_presave(Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission $webform_submission){} and a lot of variations of that - but i can't seem to get them to work, or access/dump the submission data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()** to alter webform submission data before insert:

```
function Mymodulename_webform_submission_presave(\Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission $webform_submission){
  // Get webform type/variation
  $webform_type = $webform_submission->getWebform()->id();
  if($webform_type == 'contact'){
    // Get user submitted data 
    $data = $webform_submission->getData();
    // Alter the data of title field
    $data['title'] = 'Testing tt';
    // Pass altered data 
    $webform_submission->setData($data);
  } 
}
```

Note: can pass parameter that specific to hook **Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission $webform_submission** or in this way **\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity** both are correct

You can follow [this](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave/10) refrence to read more about hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave() hook.

Comment: I disagree, I think it's better to use the actual type that's expected, rather than the generic one, for `$entity`. It's simply more accurate. It definitely isn't "incorrect" to do it that way, as your answers implies

Comment: Thanks for flagging it out , however I did not delete the ans as it's generic code to update webform submission programatically

Comment: Thanks very much, that seems to work. And in addition - if I want to dump the data, but not have to resubmit the form every time, would that be possible. If i dpm($webform_type), it dumps the webform id on the confirmation page, but if I then afterwards want to check what the $data array returns, I have to go back and fill out the form again and dpm($data). Would be nice if I could just refresh the page to give me the next dpm(), and throwing in an exit(); after the dpm($webform_type); just gives me a completely white screen. I tried var_dump(), print_r(), dump() as well with the same result.

Comment: You can use drupal logger function like this  \Drupal::logger('module_name')->notice('<pre><code>' . print_r($webform_submission->getData()), TRUE) . '</code></pre>' ); or use this function dd($webform_submission->getData()) to print webform submission data

Comment: Okay, thank you, I will have  look at those options. I have upvoted your answer :)